# Matching words with certain letters with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a line of text, for example:

```
Eimantas ėjo namo ir neparėjo
```

Is it possible to find words in this text that contains 3 different vowels (`Eimantas`, `neparėjo`) (there can be more vowels or they could be repeated) with Regex. Vowels in my language are: `AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ`.

I tried this expression but it matches words even if they have only 3 same vowels:

```
\\b\\w*[AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ]+\\w*[AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ]+\\w*[AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ]+\\w*\\b
```

I run the match ingoring cases

Comment: Your pattern seems to be [working just fine](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cw*%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%2b%5cw*%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%2b%5cw*%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%2b%5cw*%5cb&i=Eimantas+%c4%97jo+namo+ir+nepar%c4%97jo%0d%0a&o=i) with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: It also works with three of the same though.

Comment: Try [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5ba-z%5d*%28%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%29%5ba-z%5d*%28%3f!%5c1%29%28%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%29%5ba-z%5d*%28%3f!%5c1%29%28%3f!%5c2%29%5bA%c4%84E%c4%98%c4%96I%c4%aeYOU%c5%b2%c5%aa%5d%5ba-z%5d*%5cb&i=Eimantas+%c4%97jo+namo+ir+nepar%c4%97jo%0d%0aEementes+%c4%97jo+namo+ir+nepar%c4%97jo&o=i): `\b[a-z]*([AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ])[a-z]*(?!\1)([AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ])[a-z]*(?!\1)(?!\2)[AĄEĘĖIĮYOUŲŪ][a-z]*\b`